# Обмен данными между потоками

Tags: java, многопоточность, volatile

С одной стороны постоянно слышу о такой проблеме многопоточности как гонки,когда два потока могут обращаться с одними и теми же ресурсами и в результате не синхронизировано их изменять из-за чего возникают ошибки.
Но так же есть зарезервированное слово volatile ,которое можно использовать для того,что бы данные измененные в одном потоке были видны в другом.
По мне ,так тут некоторое противоречие.В первом случае потоки видят данные друг друга,а во втором для этого надо специально сообщать.
ЧТо я не понимаю?

Comment: Можно почитать в википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 1):

volatile - это переменная, значение которой не кешируется. Таким образом, в ней всегда актуальные данные. Сам же процесс перезаписи происходит атомарно, то есть, за одно мгновение относительно восприятия времени потоками, если так можно выразиться.

Answer (score 0):

Ну volatile также как и synchronized делает потокобезопасным, но если допустим 2 потока работают на разных процессорах с одним объектом то в зависимости от кеша он может быть на одном процессере в кеше в одном состоянии, а в кеше второго процессора в другом, волатайл позволяет синхронизировать и это поведение.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` не позволяет потокам копировать переменные в свой кэш. Вместо этого, потоки берут `volatile` переменные из главной копии. Поэтому, при изменении `volatile` переменной в одном потоке, она изменяется и в другом.